# Limits of functions: finding a $\delta$ for a given $\epsilon$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

So I'm given that $|f(x) - 2| < |x-1|^2, \quad |g(x)-3| < 2|x-1|, \quad |h(x)-5| < |x-1|$

and then I have to find a $0<\delta$ such that if $0<|x-1|<\delta$, then $|f(x)g(x)-h(x)-1|<1/1000$. I have already shown that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} \left( f(x)g(x) - h(x) \right)= 1$ but I don't really know how to solve for such a $\delta$?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $$fg-h-1=(f-2)(g-3)-(h-5)+2(g-3)+3(f-2)$$Then, using the triangle inequality we have $$|fg-h-1|\le|f-2||g-3|+|h-5|+2|g-3|+3|f-2|$$

$$\le2|x-1|^3+3|x-1|^2+4|x-1|$$Now, choose a $0< |x-1|=\delta$ small enough so that the right-hand side of the inequality is less than $\frac{1}{1000}$ and you'll have it!

Comment: Ah, got it, thank you very much!!

Comment: My pleasure.  For example, choose $\delta=(\frac{1}{1000})(\frac{1}{(2+3+4)})=\frac{1}{9000}$.